# Virtual Hosts Not Working under MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, osx-elcapitan

I apologize for asking a question that's be asked before, but most of those questions have not been answered, and what few answers there are have not worked for me.

I am using Dreamweaver to build and manage my sites. Until now I have been successfully testing the sites on my remote host. But I want to add a database that I can test locally, so I am trying to use MAMP to create a virtual web server on my Mac (El Capitan, 10.11.5). Following standard instructions, after installing MAMP, I have edited the following files in my /private/etc folder as follows (showing only the changes):

- etc/hosts

  ```
   127.0.0.1          localhost
   255.255.255.255    broadcasthost
   ::1                localhost 
   #127.0.0.1         fenixnest.pub.net
   #127.0.0.1         fenixnest.dev.net
   #127.0.0.1         fenixnest.tst.net
  ```
- etc/apache2/httpd.conf

  ```
  # Virtual hosts
  Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```
- etc/apache2/httpd-vhosts.conf

  ```
  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
      ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_FenixNest/"
      ServerName fenixnest.pub.net
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_FenixDev/"
      ServerName fenixnest.dev.net
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/_FenixTest/"
      ServerName fenixnest.tst.net
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Here are the results in my browsers (Safari and Chrome):

- When I enter "localhost" I get the appropriate "It Works" page.
- When I enter "localhost/fenixnest.dev.net", I get "The requested URL /fenixnest.dev.net was not found on this server." (The same for the "tst" and "pub" sites.)
- When I enter "localhost/_FenixDev" (the name of the site root folder), I get "The requested URL /_FenixDev was not found on this server."
- When I enter "fenixnest.dev.net", I get "This site can't be reached. fenixnest.tst.net’s server DNS address could not be found."

I have experimented with including "localhost/" as the prefix to the ServerName in both etc/hosts and etc/apache2/httpd-vhosts.conf. I have also tried commenting out the localhost block in etc/apache2/httpd-vhosts.conf (as suggested in one similar question). Nothing I have tried so far works.

I really would like to get a working virtual host on my Mac. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?